# Time Complexity on a TSP

Tags: time-complexity, regex-lookarounds, greedy, traveling-salesman

I am trying to analyze for each step of a TSP problem with a Greedy Algorithm and a Look-Ahead algorithm the Time Complexity.

It would be great if someone could check whether the logic that I have applied on each step makes sens to build the time complexity or not.

For the *Greedy algorithm* I have:

**Iterations: max n itinerations (n: nº of locations)**

1. Select available arc (i,j) with lowest cost **n log n operations**
   and label this arc as unavailable **1 operation**
2. Label all arcs from location i or to location j as unavailable **1 operation**
3. Label all arcs as unavailable which could result in sub cycles if more than one arc is available. **1 operation**
4. If there are still available arcs, **checking of max. n locations**
   go back to 1.

**Time Complexity**
n * ( n log n + 1 + 1 + 1 + n) --> n^2 log n + n^2 + 3n --> **O(n^2 log n)**

And for the *Look-Ahead algorithm* I have tried:

**Iterations:** **n itinerations (n: nº of locations)**

1. For each row and column, **n*n locations**
   determine available arcs with smallest and second smallest cost, **1 operation**
   and the corresponding cost difference, respectively. **1 operation**
2. Select row or column with largest cost difference and select available arc (i,j)in that row or column with lowest cost **1 operation**
   and label this arc as unavailable **1 operation**
3. Label all arcs from location ior to location j as unavailable **1 operation**
4. Label all arcs as unavailable which could result in sub cycles. **1 operation**
5. If there are still more arcs available than arcs still to be selected, go back to 1 **check n locations**
   Else: select remaining arcs. **1 operation**

**Time complexity**
n * ( n*n + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + n + 1) --> n^3 + 8n + n^2 --> n^3 --> **O(n^3)**